# VBA EnableEvents fire textbox_change

Tags: vba, events, activex

I have a textbox with code on change, and if I press a button with the following code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.EnableEvents = False

TextBox1.Text = "new text"

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

but this still fires the on change event of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `Application.EnableEvents` allows enabling/disabling events fired from the `Application` (i.e. Excel).

In your case, the parent firing the `TextBox1` change is not the `Application` but rather the `UserForm`. This is an example from [cpearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SuppressChangeInForms.htm) about *how to create your own `EnableEvents` property on your Userform*. I report the content of the link here (to avoid "link-only answer"):

> To suppress events in a form, you can create a variable at the form's
>   module level called "EnableEvents" and set that to False before
>   changing a property that will cause an event to be raised.

```
Public EnableEvents As Boolean
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub Something()
   Me.EnableEvents = False
   ' some code that would cause an event to run
   Me.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

> Then, all of the controls on form should have a test if that variable
>   as their order of business in any event code. For example,

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    If Me.EnableEvents = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    MsgBox "List Box Change"
End Sub
```

> You can declare the EnableEvents as Private if only procedures with
>   that form need to suppress events. However, if you have forms that are
>   programmatically linked together, such UserForm2 adding an item to a
>   ListBox on UserForm1, you should declare the variable as Public and
>   set it for another form with code like the following:

```
UserForm1.EnableEvents = False
'
' change something on UserForm1
'
UserForm1.EnableEvents = True
```